# Autocomplete on demand in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete

I am trying to implement a search function in angularJS pretty similar to facebook way of searching. What I found out from many a tutorials, the autocomplete directive works on data already loaded and filtering from that.
Now if the data count is huge then calling a service on page load which takes in all data would make the website slow.
Is there a possibility of making an autocomplete which loads data on demand? i.e onkeyup function if I type "dru", then for every key event a service would be called and fetch data on demand.
Thanks

Comment: Which *"autocomplete directive"*? What you're describing matches the [UI Bootstrap *Typeahead*](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) directive using a promise as source data

Comment: @Phil... Yes.But the data is already loaded in the array. What I want is the data to be populated in the array on demand. For e.g if I type "dru"  then the array should get populated with all records matching "dru"

Comment: That is **exactly** what it does via the promise-based data. See the *Asynchronous results* example; it queries `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=what-you-typed` for data **on demand**

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this by calling an API on every key stroke change.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search" ng-change="fetchSearchResults(search)">
```

> The **fetchSearchResults** method would make an api call to your server, fetching the results for the given characters as input.

Hope that made sense.